# HMAC-authenticated requests on GCS JSON API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

In GCS "migration mode", it's possible to send HMAC authenticated requests to the XML API (since it's S3 compatible). Is it possible to do the same (HMAC authenticated requests) for the JSON API too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON API does not support HMAC authentication.